# Wiremock problem with ignore requests except one

Tags: java, wiremock

I have problem with ignore all requests except one. I have the code that I need to intercept the desired request, but before that I must skip all the other requests to the server. How can i do this?

```
givenThat(any(anyUrl()).withHeader("SOAPAction", equalTo("\"Mystifly.OnePoint/OnePoint/AirRevalidate\""))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
                .withBody("{ \"message\": \"Roma Barladyn - a great colleague!\" }")
                ));
```

I also tried that but I get empty body of response, how I can send body which I get from server?

```
givenThat(any(anyUrl()).atPriority(100).willReturn(aResponse()));
```

Comment: Hey, I've answered your question but I'm not sure if I've really solved your problem. If I haven't, can you elaborate on what your precise issue is? What are you trying to do and what behavior are you seeing instead? Can you post your WireMock stub or JSON Mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sure that you check the desired request first, you can add it at the [highest priority](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/). Priority 1 will get checked before Priority 2, get checked before Priority 3, and so on. So Priority 100 in your example will get checked after Priorities 1 through 99.

```
givenThat(any(anyUrl())
    .atPriority(1)
    .withHeader("SOAPAction", equalTo("\"Mystifly.OnePoint/OnePoint/AirRevalidate\""))        
    .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
    .withBody("{ \"message\": \"Roma Barladyn - a great colleague!\" }")
    ));
```